# How to Set Request Headers Using a Feign Client?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-cloud, microservices, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-netflix

We are developing a suite of Microservices using Spring Cloud framework and one of the the things that we need to do is to set request headers. I know I can pass a parameter `@RequestHeader` to a Feign method but the value needs to come from another bean. I don't know if SPEL can be used for a Feign param value.
I was thinking that this is a common enough use case for most clients so there'd be some examples, but so far I've not found any. Of course I can dig through the Spring course code and try to override the default Feign configuration but it kinda defeats the purpose of a declarative client if I've to write a lot of code to achieve this.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 10):

I have done this before using a RequestInterceptor as follows:

```
@Component
public class MyRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
  @Override
  public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
    template.headers(getHeadersFromWherever());
  }
}
```

You can find some more useful information here:

https://github.com/Netflix/feign#user-content-setting-headers-per-target

Comment: Where do you put this? [Spring Cloud doc](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#spring-cloud-feign-overriding-defaults) states there's a `FeignClientsConfiguration ` and a `FooConfiguration`:
`@FeignClient(name = "stores", configuration = FooConfiguration.class)`
`public interface StoreClient {...}`

Comment: You can put this anywhere that is included in your @ComponentScan

Comment: If you include it in the `@ComponentScan` the interceptor will be applied to all Feign clients. On the other hand, if defined in the `FooConfiguration.class` it will be applied only to the specific FeignClient.