# How to dynamically set @Bean at @Configuration in @Service?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-feign, spring-cloud-feign

I use spring cloud & feign client with my app.And I want to set the param 'accept-language' to headers when call feign clients.
I found the similar questions at [Using @Headers with dynamic values in Feign client + Spring Cloud (Brixton RC2)

Ask][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066331/using-headers-with-dynamic-values-in-feign-client-spring-cloud-brixton-rc2),but I don't know how to set header param.Here is my code:
I set MyDefaultFeignConfig at app.java
    `@EnableFeignClients(basePackages = {defaultConfiguration = MyDefaultFeignConfig.class)`

And MyDefaultFeignConfig.java :

```
@Configuration
public class MyDefaultFeignConfig {

private String requestLanguage = "zh";

@Bean
RequestInterceptor feignRequestInterceptor() {
    return new RequestInterceptor() {
        @Override
        public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
            template.header("accept-language", requestLanguage);
        }
    };
}

//doesn't work
public static void updateBean(String requestLanguage) {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyDefaultFeignConfig.class);

    try {
        System.out.println(applicationContext.getBean("feignRequestInterceptor"));
    } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
        System.out.println("Bean not found");
    }

    BeanDefinitionRegistry beanFactory = (BeanDefinitionRegistry) applicationContext.getBeanFactory();

    beanFactory.registerBeanDefinition("feignRequestInterceptor",
            BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(String.class)
                    .addConstructorArgValue(new RequestInterceptor() {
                        @Override
                        public void apply(RequestTemplate template) {
                            template.header("accept-language", requestLanguage);
                        }
                    })
                    .getBeanDefinition()
    );

}
}
```

My Gateway controller is :

```
@Autowired
 private LeaseOrderRemoteService leaseOrderRemoteService;
 @RequestMapping(value = "/Discovery/order/unifiyInit", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Message unifiyOrderInit(@RequestHeader("accept-language") String language) {
    MyDefaultFeignConfig.updateBean(language);
    return leaseOrderRemoteService.unifiyOrderInit();
}
```

My feign clients Controller is:

```
public Message unifiyOrderInit(@RequestHeader("accept-language") String language) {
    //...
}
```

And I can only get the value of "accept-language" as MyDefaultFeignConfig  config the first time set @Bean.How can I set the value of "accept-language" from Gateway to feign client.Please help me,thinks!  Any suggestions are grateful and best regards!

Comment: You should be able to use `@RequestHeader("accept-language") String language` on the feign client itself. BTW, your question title is really vague.

Comment: thanks,spencergribb! Are you mean to add @RequestHeader("accept-language") String language in every feign client method?Is it so messy?

Comment: You can also use a `RequestInterceptor`.

Comment: Could you please explain it clearer?As I know,i can only use `RequestInterceptor` to set header when app start to inject beans.How can  i set it dynamically in methods.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: nope, request interceptors can dynamically add headers to each request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37289634/how-to-set-request-headers-using-a-feign-client/37324653#37324653